# Unsure why merge won't work after using cut() in R

Tags: r, cut, rbind

I am trying to make a new column that categorises one column in my data in to BMI categories, which I can then rbind in to a new, complete data frame. However, my current method only produces a numeric vector. As a result, this won't seem to bind back to my original data set.

Here is my code:

```
BMI_cut <- cut(alldata$BMI, 
               breaks = c(-Inf, 18.5, 25.0, 30.0, Inf),
               labels = c("<18.50", "18.50-24.99", "25.00-29.99", ">=30.00"),        
               right = FALSE)

BMIbind <- rbind(sorteddata, BMI_cut)
```

When trying this, I get the error:
Warning messages:
1: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = 2L) :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
2: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = 2L) :
  invalid factor level, NA generated

And the result is a bind with the original data and no BMI category column. The only difference is a new row with values of <NA>, 2 and 3. I can't make sense of this.

I am a complete beginner to R. Additionally, whilst there are some packages that look like they can do this much easier, I cannot use them as this is for an assignment. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: could you provide some of `alldata$BMI`  using `dput` ? Otherwise your problem can hardly [be reproduced](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610).

Comment: For the cut command you use the data.frame `alldata`, for the rbind one you use `sorteddata`. Any chance those two are not identical?

Answer (score 0):

I see quite a few problems. For once, as already mentioned in the comment above, you use tow different data.frames.

Furthermore, you seem to mix up `cbind` and `rbind`. `rbind` concats two *identical data.frames*, while `cbind` concats different columns.

Finally, this could be done by just adding another column to your data.frame like this:

```
alldata$BMI_cut <- cut(alldata$BMI, 
                       breaks = c(-Inf, 18.5, 25.0, 30.0, Inf),
                       labels = c("<18.50", "18.50-24.99", "25.00-29.99", ">=30.00"),        
                       right = FALSE)
```

For `rbind` and `cbind` compare the following:

```
> rbind(data.frame(x=1:5), data.frame(x=6:10))
    x
1   1
2   2
3   3
4   4
5   5
6   6
7   7
8   8
9   9
10 10
> cbind(data.frame(x=1:5), data.frame(x=6:10))
  x  x
1 1  6
2 2  7
3 3  8
4 4  9
5 5 10
```